# Microsoft Graph SDK for Java - InvalidAuthenticationToken error 80049217

Tags: java, angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My Authorization Client: Angular, Resource Server: Java Spring Boot, Authorization Server: Azure Active Directory

I am using oAuth2 to login via Angular via the PKCE Authorization Flow and then pass the token to the back end.
I am able to access the token in my back end via the Authorization Beaer Header, but when I go to use that token to access Microsoft Graph API, I am getting an Invalid token exception.

com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

I am not sure why it is causing this error, because its valid and I can verify via https://jwt.io/
and access my other protected api in postman with the token.

AuthProvider.java

```
public class AuthProvider implements IAuthenticationProvider {

    private String accessToken = null;

    public AuthProvider(String accessToken) {

        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticateRequest(IHttpRequest request) {
        // Add the access token in the Authorization header
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
    http.cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

GraphAPIController.java

```
private static IGraphServiceClient graphClient = null;
private static AuthProvider authProvider = null;

private static void ensureGraphClient(String accessToken) {
    if (graphClient == null) {
        // Create the auth provider
        authProvider = new AuthProvider(accessToken);

        // Create default logger to only log errors
        DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
        logger.setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.ERROR);

        // Build a Graph client
        graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .logger(logger)
                .buildClient();
    }
}

@GetMapping("/getUser")
public static User getUser(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token) {

    System.out.println("THE TOKEN: " +token);
    ensureGraphClient(token);

    // GET /me to get authenticated user
    User me = graphClient
            .me()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    System.out.println("THE USER: " + me);
    return me;
}
```

My Angular Setup:

[image]

**app.module**:
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
[image]

**app.component.ts**
[image]

Postman:
[image]

Comment: What "other protected api" can you use this token to access? Can you provide the request? Besides, please share the code about how you get the access token.

Comment: @AllenWu I have added in the addiitonal code

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An access token can only be for one resource. I can see that you configure `scope: 'openid api://{appid}/app'` in your Angular Setup. It means the access token is for this resource `api://{appid}/app` rather than Microsoft Graph `https://graph.microsoft.com`. That is why you got the InvalidAuthenticationToken Error.

So if you want to call Microsoft Graph in your backend API, you need to consider [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). The OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

In your case, your backend API is web API A and Microsoft Graph is web API B.

[image]

A [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapi) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for help! That's exactly what I was looking for. I am going to implement the On-Behalf-Of flow